# Error message running JGraphX Hello World example

Tags: java, ioexception, jgraphx

I am getting following error message when I run the HelloWorld.java example, out of JGraphX package, and move a cell by dragging and dropping it.

> java.io.IOException: Data translation failed: not an image format
>       at sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.translateTransferable(DataTransferer.java:1293)
>       at sun.lwawt.macosx.CDataTransferer.translateTransferable(CDataTransferer.java:131)
>       at sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer$6.run(DataTransferer.java:2304)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:701)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)

I am using Eclipse Juno and Java SE 7 for Mac.
I don't understand it and can't find anything to solve it. I really fall into despair. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

*Update:
Code of HelloWorld.java*

```
public class HelloWorld extends JFrame
{
    public HelloWorld()
    {
        super("Hello, World!");

        mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
        Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

        graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
        try
        {
            Object v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "Hello", 20, 20, 80, 30);
            Object v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "World!", 240, 150, 80, 30);
            graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "Edge", v1, v2);
        }
        finally
        {
            graph.getModel().endUpdate();
        }

        mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);
        getContentPane().add(graphComponent);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HelloWorld frame = new HelloWorld();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 320);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where this exception occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can workaround it by setting static field **enableImageSupport** to **false**. Like this : `com.mxgraph.swing.util.mxGraphTransferable.enableImageSupport = false;`

Source : http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/java/docs/com/mxgraph/swing/util/mxGraphTransferable.html#enableImageSupport

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be something specific to OS X and some Java versions, looking at [this bug report](http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT-706). This example works fine on the current Mac supplied JVM on OS X 10.8, namely:

```
java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03-424-11M3720)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)
```